# How to cut a string in this case in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Example:

```
let somestr = '11>22>33>44';
let someSpecificWord = '22';
```

I want to get a result like this

```
'11>22'
```

How to cut or use method for this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried subString with indexOf.. and slice

Comment: so show the code and tell us what is going wrong with it

Comment: seems like someone solved my problem in below.. thanks for regarding

Comment: @jeheechoi It feels like you didn't try very hard...

Comment: I'm junior developer and tried many times and had a lot of work to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `String#substring` with `String#lastIndexOf`:

```js
let somestr = '11>22>33>44';
let someSpecificWord = '22';

console.log(somestr.substring(0, somestr.lastIndexOf(someSpecificWord) + someSpecificWord.length));
```

Comment: oh Thanks you so much i struggled few hours!

Answer (score 0):

You can also `split()` the string to array and then find the `indexOf()` the work, then `join()` using `>` to get the final result. For better code management, create a reusable function.

```js
function cutWord(str, word){
  var splitStr = str.split('>');
  return splitStr.slice(0,splitStr.lastIndexOf(someSpecificWord)+1).join('>');
}

var somestr = '11>22>33>44';
var someSpecificWord = '22';
console.log(cutWord(somestr, someSpecificWord));

someSpecificWord = '33';
console.log(cutWord(somestr, someSpecificWord));

someSpecificWord = '11';
console.log(cutWord(somestr, someSpecificWord));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case u want all of the numbers included in result.

```js
var str = '11>22>33>44';

var splitstr = str.split('>');
var strarray =[];
for(var i=0; i<splitstr.length-1;i++){
    strarray[i] = splitstr[i]+'>'+splitstr[i+1];
    $("span").append(strarray[i]+"<br />");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span"></span>
```